# Filebeat date field mapped as type keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, elasticsearch-mapping

Filebeat is reading logs from a file, where logs are in the following format:

```
{"logTimestamp":"2019-11-29T16:39:43.027Z","@version":"1","message":"Hello world","logger_name":"se.lolotron.App","thread_name":"thread-1","level":"INFO","level_value":40000,"application":"my-app"}
```

So there is a field **logTimestamp** logged in **ISO 8601** time format.
The problem is that this field is mapped as a keyword In Elasticsearch filebeat index

```
"logTimestamp": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "ignore_above": 1024
},
```

On the other hand if I index a similar document in the same Elasticsearch instance but different index, e.g.

```
POST /new_index/_doc/
{
    "message": "hello world",
    "logTimestamp":"2019-11-29T16:39:43.027Z"
}
```

The mapping is

```
"logTimestamp": {
     "type": "date"
},
```

According to docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/dynamic-field-mapping.html#date-detection) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/mapping-date-format.html#strict-date-time) by default Elastic should detect a date if formatted with **strict_date_optional_time**. And strict_date_optional_time is described as

> A generic ISO datetime parser where the date is mandatory and the time
>   is optional.

Which I presume is ISO 8601 and think I proved that with indexing a new doc to new_index in the example above.

Why is logTimestamp saved as keyword in the case of Filebeat? Any ideas?

I'm using Filbeat 7.2.1, Elasticsearch 7.2.1.
Also the default **fields.yml** is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out that **date_detection** is disabled for filebeat indices by default (Filebeat version 7.2.1). 
This can be seen [here](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/v7.2.1/libbeat/template/template.go#L36)

```
var (
    // Defaults used in the template
    defaultDateDetection         = false
    ...
```

Does not look like it can be overridden.

The workaround for this is to use experimental feature **append_fields** (experimental at least at the time of writing this post. See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.2/configuration-template.html) for more.) and add the following to the filebeat.yml config

```
setup.template.overwrite: true
setup.template.append_fields:
- name: logTimestamp
  type: date
```

This will make sure that the mapping for logTimestamp is date.